# jQuery created Class not DOM functional

Tags: jquery, class, dom

Here's a jsFiddle test --> http://jsfiddle.net/rTXkM/

I have a button that adds a table row to my table:

```
var x = "<tr><td><button class='del'> - </button></td></tr>";
$('#mytable').append(x);
```

I also have a jQuery function that operates according to class:

```
$('.del').click(function() {
   ......................
   ......................
   ......................
});
```

However, the 'del' class click function does not work on DOM created Elements... Can someone help?

jsFiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/rTXkM/

Comment: Event delegation is what you're looking for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to delegate like this `$(document).on('click','.del',function() {`

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TJ9wT/)**

Because your `.del` elements were not there when the listener was run (inside your `.ready()` function), the element did not get a event attached to it. So you need to delegate to something that was there before to be able to catch the click on that element.

**You can read more at jQuery's documents:** [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Good answer and a little bit faster than me ;) +1

Comment: Thanks, I've been training my fingers! good answer you too :)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$(document).on("click", '.del', function() {
   alert('I work now');
}
```

and it will work. 
[jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)